# How do you find out how many vowels are in a word?

Tags: python

I have a love calculator that shows how much name1 and name2 are in love (out of 100%), depending if the number of vowels match or not. Here is my code so far:

```
name1 = input("Please type Name 1.\n")
name2 = input("Please type Name 2.\n")
vowels1 = 0
vowels2 = 0
VOWELS = 'aeiou'
def up_it(word):
    letters = []
    for letter in name1:
        if letter.lower() in VOWELS:
            vowels1 = 1+vowels1 
print("You have",vowels1,"vowels.")
```

It doesn't show how many vowels there are in name1. How do you make it so that it does show how many vowels are in name1?

Comment: You defined a function `up_it` but didn't call it.

Comment: Did you call your function? You pass `word` to function and is not used inside. Apart from that, this should work fine.

Comment: @sal, `return` isn't necessary as `vowels1` is in global scope.

Comment: @Austin, yes, I noticed. The code is very confusing, probably as much as the OP. I'll add a little better solution as well.

Comment: I used several other codes found in answers of other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def up_it(word):
    vowel =['a','e','i','o','u']
    count =0
    for i in vowel:
        count+=word.count(i)
    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than defining a function that modifies a global variable, you should create a function that *returns* the solution directly. That way it doesn't depend on some fragile global state.

```
def count_vowels(word):
    vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}  # I use a set here rather than a list because
                                        # sets have very fast membership checks.
    count = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter in vowels:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Then you can simply do:

```
num_vowels = count_vowels(name1)
```

---

Possibly worth noting is that `count_vowels` can be reduced to a one-liner:

```
def count_vowels(word):
    return sum(lett in {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'} for lett in word)
```

Comment: I would change last generator to `sum(lett in {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'} for lett in word)`.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a function `up_it(word)` but didn't call it. Below a simplified version of the code:

```
name1 = input("Please type Name 1.\n")
name2 = input("Please type Name 2.\n")
vowels1 = 0
vowels2 = 0
VOWELS = 'aeiou'

def up_it(word):
    letters = []
    for letter in name1:
        if letter.lower() in VOWELS:
            vowels1 = 1+vowels1 

up_it(name1)  # call the function
print("You have", vowels1, "vowels.")
```

Now, that code doesn't really make correct use of functions. A better way would be to make the function take (and use) a parameter, and return the count value. With that in mind we would have something like this:

```
def count_vowels(word):
    VOWELS = 'aeiou'
    vowels_count = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter.lower() in VOWELS:
            vowels_count += 1
    return vowels_count

name1 = input("Please type Name 1.\n")
name2 = input("Please type Name 2.\n")
print("You have", count_vowels(name1), "vowels.")
print("You have", count_vowels(name2), "vowels.")
```

Answer (score 0):

`vowels1 = len([letter for letter in name1 if letter.lower() in VOWELS])`

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it should work - for name1 anyway - you just forgot to call up_it().
so try this:

```
def up_it(word):
    letters = []
    for letter in name1:
        if letter.lower() in VOWELS:
            vowels1 = 1+vowels1 

name1 = input("Please type Name 1.\n")
name2 = input("Please type Name 2.\n")
vowels1 = 0
vowels2 = 0
VOWELS = 'aeiou'

up_it("literally anything because you don't use the value passed")

print("You have",vowels1,"vowels.")
```

The problem is that the up_it function you defined never actually uses the passed in variable word. It always uses name1. Also you have a list called letters being declared and initialized but you never use it in the method.

I think what you really want is the following code:

```
def up_it(word):
    word = word.lower()
    return sum([word.count(vowel) for vowel in 'aeiou'])

name1 = input("Please type Name 1.\n")
name2 = input("Please type Name 2.\n")

vowels_name_1 = up_it(name1)
vowels_name_2 = up_it(name2)

print(name1,"has", vowels_name_1,"vowels.")
print(name2,"has", vowels_name_2,"vowels.")
```